# Regarding frames in HTML

Tags: html

I am making GUI for making configurations.

The problem I am facing is, that I have divided it into frame sets, but there are places where on the click action of the button the window that is to be opened overlaps other frame which I am not able to do.

If I use HTML5, how is it possible that way too? Please Explain.

Comment: Can you share your code ...

Comment: show what you have done yet? also post some screenshots so we can see output.

Comment: I have used framesets like this:

Answer (score 0):

I have used framesets like this:
 
         
             
             
         
         Home

I have a image inside the node info frame, and on onclick event we want to ovarlap the node info frame over admin_node_menu frame so that it gives a zoom effect.
something like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ch5j1.png)